# User Email field unavailable to community user sharing?

Tags: sharing, user, customer-community

Is the Email field in the User object hidden from customer community users?  My client has customer community and has written an application for the community.  There is an Apex class "with sharing" that selects various fields from the User object.  When a community user accesses this method, all field values are returned except for the Email field, which returns a null value.

When a standard license user performs the same function, the email value is returned.

Portal User Visibility and Community User Visibility is enabled.  There is a sharing rule on the User object and all the community users are in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For community users, there are 3 levels of visibility for their data fields:  Employee, External, Public.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_contact_info_visibility.htm&language=en

These can be set in the API using fields such as UserPreferencesShowEmailToExternalUsers, etc.

Comment: Also, if the Apex class uses without sharing, then the Email will always be visible.